# Jackson serialization using JsonTypeInfo WRAPPER_OBJECT

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jackson

I am trying to set subclass name as the XML element name in the serialized XML content using Jackson in the following manner.

```
public interface Animal {
    public String getName();
}

public class Dog implements Animal {
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

public class Cat implements Animal {
    private String name;
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}

public class Zoo {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JsonTypeInfo(include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = Id.NAME)
    private List<Animal> animals;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Result:

```
<Zoo>
    <animals>
        <Dog>
            <name>xyz</name>
        </Dog>
    </animals>
    <animals>
        <Cat>
            <name>abc</name>
        </Cat>
    </animals>
</Zoo>
```

By adding `@JsonTypeInfo(include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = Id.NAME)`, I am able to set class name as the wrapper object. Is it possible to eliminate `<animal/>` wrapper and generate the XML in the below format:

```
<Zoo>
    <Dog>
        <name>xyz</name>
    </Dog>
    <Cat>
        <name>abc</name>
    </Cat>
</Zoo>
```

Comment: It's the name of the list, so you can't do that. You are trying to break serialization rules.

Comment: Thanks for your response... Since we are adding a WRAPPER_OBJECT, using @JsonTypeInfo, list wrapper is not required. This can be achieved in JAXB using @XmlElements({ @XmlElement() }) annotations. Was wondering whether we can achieve that in Jackson (maybe by implementing custom serialization ?). Please share your thoughts...

Answer (score 2):

I was able find out an answer myself. We can achieve this using a custom serializer as illustrated below.

```
public class Zoo {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JsonSerialize(using=AnimalListSerializer.class)
    private List<Animal> animals;
    // getters and setters
}

public class AnimalListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<Animal>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(List<Animal> value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {

        for (Animal me : value) {
            provider.defaultSerializeField(me.getClass().getName(), me,
                    jgen);
        }
    }
}
```